# TSQL Multi-Part Identifier Could Not Be Found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are attempting to update the `LastUpdateDateTime` column to the value of the `Stamp` column in another database, on another server via this query:

```
update [NEWTON-DB].NEWTON.dbo.vital_signs 
set lastupdatedatetime = 
    coalesce ((select top 1 stamp 
               from [SERVER2].NEWTON.dbo.vital_sign 
               where rowguid in (select oldrowguid 
                                 from [NEWTON-DB].NEWTON.dbo.import_log 
                                 where tablename = 'vital_sign' 
                                   and newid = [NEWTON-DB].NEWTON.dbo.vital_signs.id)), 
              coalesce(lastupdatedatetime, getutcdate()))
```

The import_log table is simply the inner join to fetch the new id based off the old `rowguid` if that makes any sense.

When they were on the same server this query worked fine, but after migrating I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "NEWTON-DB.NEWTON.dbo.vital_signs.id" could not be bound.

Is there something blindingly obvious we're missing. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What is the data type of newid?

Comment: Both the id and newid are nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 Part identifers like this `[NEWTON-DB].NEWTON.dbo.vital_signs.id` don't work

You need to alias the table and then use the alias

e.g.

```
Select top 1 stamp 
from [SERVER2].NEWTON.dbo.vital_sign t
where rowguid in (select oldrowguid 
                    from [NEWTON-DB].NEWTON.dbo.import_log 
                    where tablename = 'vital_sign' 
                    and newid = t.id)
```